# Matrix functions to compute a correlation matrix in conjunction with an IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, matrix, correlation

I am trying to calculate several correlation matrices using matrix functions in Excel. I have no difficulty with a straightforward problem but when I want to compute three matrices based on three unique values of a variable I am not able to get the IF statement to work properly.

Specifically I have three scenarios ("risk loving", "normal", "risk averse") coded in say `B2:B253`. My return data is in `C2:C253`.  My goal is to create three correlation matrices depending on the values in column `B`.  My code is:

```
=MMULT(IF(B2:B253="RISK LOVING",TRANSPOSE($C$2:$L$253-$O$3:$X$3),$C$2:$L$253-$O$3:$X$3)/$P$1/MMULT(TRANSPOSE($O$4:$X$4),$O$4:$X$4),0). Any suggestions?
```

Answer (score 0):

The left hand side of the condition is a range (B2:B253). The right hand side is a value. I believe that the first comparisson results in a true if and only if it is true for B2. Is this really what you want to do? Or do you like to have a column of IF statements.